# Three dimensional Riemann tensor on a manifold with degenerate metric

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, mathematical-physics, curvature, semi-riemannian-geometry

Disclaimer: In this post I'm using abstract index notation. In particular brackets around indices indicates anti-symmetrization:

$$A_{[a}B_{b]}=\frac{1}{2}(A_aB_b-A_bB_a).$$

Let $\mathcal{I}$ be a smooth three-dimensional manifold with a degenerate metric $q_{ab}$ with signature $(0,+,+)$. This is the structure of null infinity in general relativity.

In Eq. (3.3) of [[1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.1800)] the author claims:

> Since $\mathcal{I}$ is $3$-dimensional, the curvature tensor $R_{abc}^{\phantom{abc}d}$ of any $D$ [a metric compatible connection] is completely determined by a second rank tensor $S_a^{\phantom{a}b}$ $$R_{abc}^{\phantom{abc}d} = q_{c[a}S_{b]}^{\phantom{b]}d}+S_{c[a}\delta_{b]}^{\phantom{b]}d},\tag{3.3}$$
>   where $S_{ab}=S_a^{\phantom{a}c}q_{bc}$.

Now, why is that? Unfortunatelly the author provides no reference, so that it seems this is a trivial fact. Still I couldn't think of any proof that uses the dimension of $\mathcal{I}$ being $3$.

So how can we show that the Riemann curvature tensor of any metric compatible connection in a three-dimensional manifold can be encoded in a second rank tensor $S_a^{\phantom{a}b}$ as in Eq. (33)?

---

[1 - Geometry and Physics of Null Infinity - Abhay Ashtekar;](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.1800)

Comment: Have you come across the [Ricci decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_decomposition) before? Remember that in 3 dimensions the Weyl curvature vanishes.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis thanks for the reference. I haven't read about the Ricci decomposition before, really. I'm going to read the page carefully, I believe that this decomposition is the answer to my question.